# How to show a chooser dialog even if the URI is an App Links one

Tags: android

[The reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_CHOOSER) about `android.content.Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER` says:

> … all possible activities will always be shown even if one of them is currently marked as the preferred activity.

[The one](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations) about the App Links says:

> No dialog; your app opens to handle your website links

I think these are antinomy.

For example, does the following chooser for an App Links URI show a dialog or not? On my test, no dialogs are shown.

```java
package com.example.applinkchooser;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(<an app links uri>);

        Intent uriIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(uriIntent, null));

        finish();
    }
}
```

Then my question is how to show a chooser dialog even if the URI is an App Links one. Must I use [`android.content.pm.PackageManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager)?

Answer (score 1):

If the SDK is M or later, you must add MATCH_ALL to the flag.

```
int appsFlag = PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    appsFlag = PackageManager.MATCH_ALL;
}

PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent urlIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = pm.queryIntentActivities(urlIntent, appsFlag);
```

Comment: Apps without one having App Links are not shown even if this solution.